# Collapsible slide out menu

Tags: android, slider

Any suggestions on how to implement vertical collapsible slide out menu in android. Similar to android ExpandableListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by adding a dynamic LinearLayout as a ListView item...